.Net Garbage Collection when using Interop.Access
I use the following code to open Access (via Interop.Access dll version 9.0.0.0) and display a report for the user. In looking at Task Manager, when this is executed Access first appears in the Processes section and once Access opens on the desktop it appears in the Apps section and is no longer in the Processes section. When the user closes Access it again appears in the Processes section and is never Garbage Collected. I thought by setting the local variable (accRPT) to Nothing and the fact it goes out of scope this would force it to be removed. If I add GC.Collect and GC.Wait after declaring the variable Nothing in the Finally clause it does remove Access from the Task Manage. My question is what is the correct way to use Interop.Access in this situation?
    Dim accRpt As New Access.Application
    Try
        accRpt.Application.OpenCurrentDatabase(dataBasePath)  
        accRpt.DoCmd.OpenReport(LOAD_TENDER_REPORT_NAME_EMAIL, Access.AcView.acViewPreview)    
        accRpt.Application.Visible = True
        accRpt.DoCmd.Maximize()
    Catch ex As Exception
            ErrHandler(" View Report ", ex)
    Finally
        accRpt = Nothing             
    End Try


Setting accRpt to Nothing will cause it to be eventually garbage collected.  When that happens, any referenced objects that have finalizers (e.g. Process) will be queued for finalization.  And once the pending finalizers are executed the unmanaged resources will get freed.  This is what you are seeing.

Access.Application does not implement IDisposable so Using accRpt As New Access.Application is not applicable.  In How to automate Microsoft Access by using Visual C# MSFT calls accRpt.Quit(Access.AcQuitOption.[Your option here]);  so maybe you should also.

Calling Quit was the solution. Thank you dbc for the link.

"When the user closes Access it again appears in the Processes section and is never Garbage Collected" - GC has absolutely nothing to do with however Task Manager displays a process...

On the other hand those same docs also indicate that one should call Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accRpt). And, while about Excel not Access, How to properly release Excel COM objects and Releasing COM objects: Garbage Collector vs. Marshal.RelseaseComObject agree.
